# How to add image on header in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

I am using Gabriele Mariotti navigation drawer library to create the sliding menu. It works perfect, but I'm facing with adding an image, as header in it. It should look something like this:

[image]

I mean.. not exactly the same, but the idea of having the image as header. Thanks !

**MainActivity:**

```
package ro.volunteer;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NewsFeed extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] menuItems;


    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newsfeed);


        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _initMenu();
        mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }


    private void _initMenu() {
        NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);



        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);


        // Add Header
        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);

        // Add first block

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items);
        String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon);

        int res = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems) {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                    this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res],
                    "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            if (res==1) mItem.counter=0; //it is just an example...
            if (res==3) mItem.counter=0; //it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res++;
        }

        mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header2);

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items2);
        String[] menuItemsIcon1 = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.ns_menu_items_icon3);

        int res2 = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems) {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                    this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon1[res2],
                    "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            if (res2==1) mItem.counter=0; //it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res2++;
        }

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        if (mDrawerList != null)
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        /*
         * The action bar home/up should open or close the drawer.
         * ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
         */
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle your other action bar items...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

        public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout){
            super(
                mActivity,
                mDrawerLayout, 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.ns_menu_open, 
                R.string.ns_menu_close);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_close));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.ns_menu_open));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);         
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            if (position == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(NewsFeed.this, Profile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                mDrawer.closeDrawers();
            }


        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
        }
```

**Adapter:**

```
 package ro.volunteer;


    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class NsMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NsMenuItemModel> {

        /*
         * public NsMenuAdapter(Context context, int resource, int
         * textViewResourceId, String[] objects) { super(context,
         * R.layout.ns_menu_row, textViewResourceId, objects); }
         */

        public NsMenuAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        public void addHeader(int title) {
            add(new NsMenuItemModel(title, -1, true));
        }

        public void addItem(int title, int icon) {
            add(new NsMenuItemModel(title, icon, false));
        }

        public void addItem(NsMenuItemModel itemModel) {
            add(itemModel);

        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return getItem(position).isHeader ? 0 : 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return !getItem(position).isHeader;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
            public final TextView textHolder;
            public final ImageView imageHolder;
            public final TextView textCounterHolder;

            public ViewHolder(TextView text1, ImageView image1,TextView textcounter1) {
                this.textHolder = text1;
                this.imageHolder = image1;
                this.textCounterHolder=textcounter1;
            }
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            NsMenuItemModel item = getItem(position);
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null) {
                int layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row_counter;
                if (item.isHeader)
                    layout = R.layout.ns_menu_row_header;

                view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layout, null);

                TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_title);
                text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_icon);
                TextView textcounter1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menurow_counter);

                view.setTag(new ViewHolder(text1, image1,textcounter1));
            }

            if (holder == null && view != null) {
                Object tag = view.getTag();
                if (tag instanceof ViewHolder) {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) tag;
                }
            }


            if(item != null && holder != null)
            {
                if (holder.textHolder != null)
                    holder.textHolder.setText(item.title);

                if (holder.textCounterHolder != null){
                    if (item.counter > 0){
                        holder.textCounterHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.textCounterHolder.setText(""+item.counter);
                    }else{
                        holder.textCounterHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                if (holder.imageHolder != null) {
                    if (item.iconRes > 0) {
                        holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.imageHolder.setImageResource(item.iconRes);
                    } else {
                        holder.imageHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }

            return view;        
        }

    }



**ItemModel:**


package ro.volunteer;


public class NsMenuItemModel {

    public int title;
    public int iconRes;
    public int counter;
    public boolean isHeader;

    public NsMenuItemModel(int title, int iconRes,boolean header,int counter) {
        this.title = title;
        this.iconRes = iconRes;
        this.isHeader=header;
        this.counter=counter;
    }

    public NsMenuItemModel(int title, int iconRes,boolean header){
        this(title,iconRes,header,0);
    }

    public NsMenuItemModel(int title, int iconRes) {
        this(title,iconRes,false);
    }



}
```

Comment: Where is your code for the header layout?

Comment: It doesn't have any layout.. The header, I mean this:  `mAdapter.addHeader(R.string.ns_menu_main_header);` is just a text from string. But I don't want text, I would like to have an image instead of text.

Comment: Does the addHeader method allow for another parameter, such as a view you've created? I'm not familiar with the library.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can give u the library. [link](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/androiddev/tree/master/NavigationDrawer)   . Thanks !

Comment: If the library doesn't support it, then you'll have to ask the author to update it. Rather than that though, the navigation drawer isn't any more complicated than a normal layout view. You can add whatever you want to it.... If you follow some other examples out there, you'll see after a bit of practice it's not too tricky....

Comment: Can you recommand me other libraries which supports that? Thanks !